# getting the "failed to query the available providers" message after Terraform init cmd

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

```
PS C:\Users\D~\master_terraform\01_aws> terraform init -upgrade

Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding hashicorp/aws versions matching "~> 4.0"...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/ami...
- Installing hashicorp/aws v4.39.0...
- Installed hashicorp/aws v4.39.0 (signed by HashiCorp)
╷
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/ami: provider registry registry.terraform.io
│ does not have a provider named registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/ami
│
│ All modules should specify their required_providers so that external consumers will get the correct providers when
│ using a module. To see which modules are currently depending on hashicorp/ami, run the following command:
│     terraform providers
```

```
PS C:\Users\D~\master_terraform\01_aws> terraform init

Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Reusing previous version of hashicorp/aws from the dependency lock file
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/ami...
- Using previously-installed hashicorp/aws v4.31.0
╷
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/ami: provider registry registry.terraform.io
│ does not have a provider named registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/ami
│
│ All modules should specify their required_providers so that external consumers will get the correct providers when
│ using a module. To see which modules are currently depending on hashicorp/ami, run the following command:
│     terraform providers
╵
```

i was expecting it to go ahead and initialize so i can apply to my infrastructure

Comment: Can you also share your terraform code without the secrets? At least the providers and backed configuration

Comment: Wow, you posted a screenshot with your credentials. Never do that. You are obviously referencing a resource in a wrong way and it seems it's related to AMI.

Comment: thanks for your interest in helping me solve this, oh yes it totally skipped my mind to change back into variables..

Comment: Make sure to delete the image from imgur as well and revoke the previous key pair.

Comment: please i still need help to the initial question. and i would appreciate any help. yes its Ami related

Comment: Just add the code you have, and please omit the provider block now.